# Magento 2 : Update layout handle from XML by condition

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3.1

This is my layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="my_custom_layout_1" />
    <update handle="my_custom_layout_2" />
</page>
```

I want to update handle `my_custom_layout_2` if value from system configuration is "abc" otherwise, I don't want to update that handle.

How to do that ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hvae you tied using `ifconfing` as I guess it is not possible to do layout update like that.

Comment: @Korbin, We can not use ifconfig for update handle.

Comment: Ifconfig will not working. Ifconfig only use for boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using **Controller action**

You can use below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ){
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $config = $this->getConfig('test/test/test');
        if($config){
            $resultPage->addHandle('my_custom_layout_1');
        }else{
            $resultPage->addHandle('my_custom_layout_2');
        }

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Is it any possible way via xml?

Comment: @Niket, we can add ifconfig condition in block but you need to update handler so you need to follow that using Controller or using Observer only. You can't do that using XML. Hope my answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Your code is not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Yes sure let me know what you did here?

Comment: I created one layout.xml for 1column and other layout.xml for rest of layout and add condition like that as you post. But, it's not update. If I do with controller's layout file (question file) then it's working.

Comment: Okay I'll send you one example within hour then I'll send module's link here

Comment: You can download this example (https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-layout-handler-example) and run with http://www.example.com/layout_handler

Comment: So you will get idea how it will work. And you can add your condition in Controller's file. Let me know still you have any issues there then.

Comment: Above solution works for you ?

Comment: Nope...........

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin

https://github.com/DominicWatts/MaintenancePage/blob/1a1ce757adae972f6b5435e33da11ea21d5312a0/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Layout.php#L30-L43

```
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $subject
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterAddDefaultHandle(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $subject
    ) {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        if ($this->pageHelper->isEnabled($storeId) && !$this->pageHelper->isDevAllowed($storeId)) {
            $subject->addHandle('maintenance_page_mode');
        }
        return $subject;
    }
```

See how it's based on config

https://github.com/DominicWatts/MaintenancePage/blob/1a1ce757adae972f6b5435e33da11ea21d5312a0/Helper/Page.php#L67-L79

```
    /**
     * Maintenance page
     * @param null $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function isEnabled($storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_MAINTENANCE_ENABLED,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
    }
```

Comment: Is it any possible way via xml?

Comment: You can define defaults in XML. You dont have to have system.xml show options in store configuration